# NetBeans IDE Recognize a Grails application as a Maven project

Tags: maven, grails, netbeans

Is there a way to have NetBeans recognize a Grails application as a Maven Project?  I opened a Grails application in NetBeans that was built using Maven.  Because the packaging element in the pom.xml contains the value 'grails-app', instead of values such as war, jar, pom, etc., NetBeans identifies the project as a Grails application which then prevents the project from resolving all the Groovy services that it needs.  Here is a snippet of the pom.xml used to build the project:

```
<artifactId>MPF-SalesQuote</artifactId>
<packaging>grails-app</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Here are some of the error messages I am receiving when I attempt to run the project:

```
LogoutController.groovy: 18: unable to resolve class   grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
@ line 18, column 1.
 import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

LogoutController.groovy: 19: unable to resolve class org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured
 @ line 19, column 1.
 import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured

UserController.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured
@ line 4, column 1.
 import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured
^
```

I believe if I can get NetBeans to identify the project as a Maven project instead of a Grails application, this would take of the problem of Groovy services not being resolved.

Answer (score 0):

any project with pom.xml is recognized as maven project, any packaging specific functionality is on top of base support.

if your project is recognized as something else, it's likely you have /nbproject folder in the base project folder. project recognition ordering is hardwired and maven pom.xml comes after /nbproject  in most cases. the only workaround Afaik is to delete /nbproject and restart the ide. then it should load as maven project.